# What is this Korean fox girl video game from an advertisement?

Tags: game-identification

I saw the following ad for some kind of Korean video game during a Starcraft match:

[image: fox girl game]

What is this game?

Comment: Effective advertisement.

Comment: Q: "What is this game whose title is written in huge text on the ad?"  A: "It appears to be a game called <title that is written in huge text on the ad>." ... Lol ...

Comment: @JasonC To be fair, probably most people here can't read Korean.

Comment: PSA: This game is basically a copy of Summoner's War, which in my opinion is better in every way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears to be a game called 몬스터슈퍼리그 (translit: *monseuteosyupeoligeu*), which translates as *Monster Super League*.

Here are the links:

[Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftt.msleague_gl)
[App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/monseuteosyupeoligeu/id1092463295)

Comment: playstore description seems to already be in English: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ftt.msleague_gl

Comment: or "Monsanto Superglue"

Comment: same on the app store.